# Passing an argument from the second to the first dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have two `dialog fragments`.

I have a `TextView` in the first `dialog fragment` and when user clicks on the it, takes you to the second `dialog fragment` where a user adds comments in the `EditText`. When user finishes typing his comments ,and clicks on `done` button to go back to the first `dialog fragment`. So far so good and works.

My question is how to pass and assign an argument(`user comment`) to the first `dialog fragment textView`?

**First DialogFragment**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Report:DialogFragment
    {
        String comment;
        public Report ()
        {
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Report, container, false);
            var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.comment);

            textView.Click += TextView_Click;
            return view;
        }

        void TextView_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowDialog ();
        }

        public void ShowDialog()
        {
            var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            var dialogFragment = new Comment();
            dialogFragment.Show(transaction, "dialog_fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

**Second DialogFragment**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Comment:DialogFragment
    {   

        EditText comment;

        public Comment ()
        {
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Comment, container, false);

            comment = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.myText);

            Button doneBtn = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.doneBtn);
            doneBtn.Click += DoneBtn_Click;
            return view;
        }

        void DoneBtn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String str = comment.Text;
            Console.WriteLine (str);
            this.Dismiss ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything?  There's plenty of information out there.

Comment: It is C#- Xamarin.Android platform

Comment: I have done research and come to know how to pass from the first to second dialog fragment. I do not know how to make it from second to first dialog. It is unwind. If you share any useful link, I would be glad.

Comment: You can look at [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Sorry Rick, I could not able to find informative information from the link. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer:

I have added the following code in the second dialog fragment:

```
void DoneBtn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String str = comment.Text;
   // the following lines are added
   Bundle args = new Bundle ();
   args.PutString ("comment", str);
   var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
   var dialogFragment = new Report();
   dialogFragment.Arguments= args;
   dialogFragment.Show(transaction, "dialog_fragment");
   this.Dismiss ();
}
```

I have added the following code in the first dialog fragment:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   // the following lines are added
    Bundle args = Arguments;
    if (args != null) {
      String returnString = args.GetString ("comment");
    }
}

void TextView_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowDialog ();
 // dismiss the first dialogFragment
    this.Dismiss ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint.  In your second fragment create a method like this and call it from your DoneBtn_Click :

```
private void sendResult(int resultCode,Date date) {
    if(getTargetFragment() == null) {
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME,date);

        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(),resultCode,intent);
}
```

And in your first fragment, implement onActivityResult. This is java but you should get the idea.

Comment: Hi Rick, but I am dismissing the second `dialog fragment`, you are using `Intent`? I have upvoted your effort.

Comment: Never mind, I have got the solution and added below.